# Javascript, trying to get date part time only

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a date field coming from SQL as follows:

> 2022-06-30T00:00:00.000Z

Im trying to get the first 10 characters (date in format yyyy-mm-dd) from it, but I can't get it to work.

First, I tried a "left" function

```
textPaidThru= pt.slice(0,10)
```

And I got

> Wed Jun 29

Then I tried moment

```
let textPaidThru = moment(paidThru).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

But Im getting this:

> 2022-06-29

No matter which method I try to use, I always get the provided date minus one day.

I encounter working with dates very hard in JS. Is there a way to get the date part only as provided by SQL? This is the value Im expecting:

> 2022-06-30

Thanks.

Comment: The date field in the database is probably (hopefully!) a timestamp which doesn't have a "format" per se, but is just a number representing an instant. So when you do your query, unless you tell us, how you convert your timestamp to a string nobody can help you. But most certainly, this is a timezone issue, because if you are in a timezone, that is behind UTC, the `2022-06-30T00:00:00.000Z` is still the `2022-06-29` in local time

Comment: Hi Derpirscher. Im in US Mountain time (CO). I didn't know the time zone had something to do with the value coming from SQL. I wanted to treat the field coming from SQL as a simple string, but I cannot even convert it to string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR; Timezones

### Actual Answer

You could just use some vanilla javascript and parse it like this:

Note month is zero index in Date, so you will need to add 1 to each:

```js
const dateToParse = "2022-06-30T00:00:00.000Z"
let parsedDate =  new Date(dateToParse)
const formattedDate = `${parsedDate.getFullYear()}-${parsedDate.getMonth()+1}-${parsedDate.getDate()}`
console.log(formattedDate)
```

The reason you are getting 6-29 is most likely due to you not living in UTC+0. I get 6-29 as well, but that is because I live in UTC-7.

If you look in the code below I change the time to be UTC-7 (which should work for your timezone as well if what your profile says is correct UTC-3) and the console log for me displays 6-30 now.

```js
const dateToParse = "2022-06-30T07:00:00.000Z"
let parsedDate =  new Date(dateToParse)
const formattedDate = `${parsedDate.getFullYear()}-${parsedDate.getMonth()+1}-${parsedDate.getDate()}`
console.log(formattedDate)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. So adding UTC -7 is the only solution? There is no way to convert a date to string and get the first 10 values?

Comment: This worked Daniel. I feel uncomfortable with the way JS works, or maybe it is me. I cannot understand how its not possible to convert a date to string and then do a slice.... but I believe its just me. I added 7 hours to the date provided by SQL and that worked. Thanks Daniel.

Comment: @Danielle I was saying 7 works for me. For you use whatever timezone you are in (I think you are UTC-3 if your profile is correct)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Still... what a disaster is to work with dates in JS. I come from .NET, where now() is the server time... switching to Node makes working with dates a terrible experience for me. Thanks a lot Daniel.

Comment: @Danielle Javascript's date library was *stolen* from Java in 1995. Java then did a complete overhaul of their date library 2 years later because it was SO BAD. However, Javascript needs backwards compatability or else website will break, so we are stuck with it. There is a new version of the date library, but it's not a web standard yet. Here's a link about it from the first hit I found on DuckDuckGo https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-temporal-api-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

If you know you'll always get the same format (well, you probably will), you can just use `split`, something like.

```
let dateTime = '2022-03-25T02:03:04.000Z';
let onlyDate = date.split('T')[0];
```

This will split the string at `T` and you basically only want the first part (array index 0) and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This didn't work for me, and if I convert the variable to string Im getting this result: Wed Mar 30 2022 17:00:00 GM for 2022-03-31T00:00:00.000Z